# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 2 [character 3 line 1]

Tags: java, json

The following program I am trying to  call a stackexchange api to get a response in JSON.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonReader {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/4614124?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
  }
}
```

When I am running these I am getting following error, but response object begins with { only .

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 2 [character 3 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:184)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
    at JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(JsonReader.java:28)
    at JsonReader.main(JsonReader.java:36)
```

Comment: What is the content of your returned JSON ? does it start with '{' ?

Comment: what is the content of `jsonText` at `new JSONObject(jsonText);`

Comment: Yes it starting with '{'

Comment: are you sure you get the expected result?

Comment: have you tried `new JSONObject(json.toString()); ` directly?

Comment: @Jens . Yes I am sure

Comment: @Frank The to convert that in to string , I am not getting a response in human readable format

Comment: When I run your code the jsonText has the value �uQ�N�0�z���͋H�����&����v��پ��mwgfg��f:��Y�����:��&Ѐzg��:�����s��AQq��3Wh��*/yZEL{��4�I���1b� �����4˒��qN
�� hk���P

Comment: Its not a valid json , It wont parse . valid json is like : {"key" : "value"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response coming from the url is compressed with Gzip. You need to uncompress the input stream before reading it. This is done by wrapping the InputStream with a GZIPInputStream.

```
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is);
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot . Works like charm .